# How to delete a specifc csv row in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have many thousands of lines in a CSV file.

```
1|row1
2|row2
3|row3
4|row4
```

etc.

I read in row1 and then do some operation.

I then want to delete row1 so my CSV file is now:

```
1|row2
2|row3
3|row4
```

All of the solutions I have found seem to relate to skipping the header which is not what I'm trying to do. On the next iteration I would be deleting row2 and then the next iteration row3.

Comment: are you writing out to the file after each operation? if not why not just process the file and then delete the file afterwards?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read csv file into data frame
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# Perform your operation on row1
row1 = df.iloc[0,:]

# Delete row 1 from the data frame
df = df.iloc[1:,:].reset_index(drop=True)

# df now contains everything in the csv except row 1

# Save new csv as desired
df.to_csv('file.csv') # This will overwrite the original csv file
```

You can loop the code above and it will delete the new first row of the csv each time.

Comment: OP says `on the next iteration i would be deleting row2 and then the next iteration row3` so this answer is not correct

Comment: actually this is fine as row2 would be the new row1

Answer (score -1):

You can just put all the lines of your csv file in a list via `readlines()` and then delete the line you want. For example:

```
f = open("mycsvfile.csv")
l = f.readlines()

for i in l:
    ...  # do some operation

    del l[i]  # delete the line
```

Comment: please format your code, also this deletes it from a list that you read in, not the actual CSV file itself